# RVIZ doesnot show /camera_link when kinect is connected

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run openni_launch for kinect and open the RVIZ, I don't get the "/camera_link" in the drop down of the fixed frame in the global options. it always show map.

Because of this I am unable to visualise the point cloud from the kinect.

Any idea why this is happening..?

many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188913/rviz-doesnot-show-/camera_link-when-kinect-is-connected/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
What did you put in glabal option in rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Restarting the PC, has solved the problem ,but I am not sure what is the cause for this.

---

Originally posted by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) with karma: 86 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1